# Change Next Full Crawl date

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, crawling

Is it possible to set when the next full crawl date will be?

I have to crawl 2 content sources every 4 weeks but I want them to be running every 2 weeks. For example:

- 01/Jan - intranet1
- 15/Jan - Intranet2
- 29/Jan - Intranet1
- 12/Feb - Intranet2 and so on

I think if I wait 2 weeks after I schedule the crawl for intranet1, I can schedule the crawl for intranet2 to start.

Is there a better way to do that? A PS command to set the Next Full Crawl date?

Comment: Is there a reason you're running a full crawl? Ideally you only run an FC under conditions which require it (new content source, new managed property, etc).

Comment: Not sure if there really is a reason. But apparently it's been like that for years and they want to keep it like that. So I am looking for alternatives to make the crawl become "alternate" without waiting 2 weeks to have the other crawl scheduled

Comment: The only way to schedule it like that would be to do something via Windows Task Scheduler and manually do so via PoSh. But a FC shouldn't be performed as it reduces the freshness of the index until the crawl is completed. This versus using Continuous Crawl which is nearly always fresh.

Comment: Thanks Trevor, I agree with you but unfortunately I will have to sticky with the FC. I guess I will wait for 2 weeks until I reschedule the craw for the 2nd intranet.

Answer (score 3):

Go to your content source and click on edit.

[image]

Scroll below and you will find Schedule for Full Crawl. Below you will have a "Edit Schedule" link.

[image]

A pop up opens as below
[image]

Do the same for both the content sources by changing the weeks schedule.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The main problem with that is that I don't have control over the date that the crawl is starting. So let's say I want my crawl to start Monday 3AM - but I do not want the following Monday (30/10), I want Monday in 2 weeks (13/11). So as far as I can see, the only way is to wait 2 more weeks to schedule the crawl - I just didn't want to wait.